# I am Getting email in HTML code

Tags: php, html, email

I developed a mobile version for shopping cart. I am facing email issue in this part..

When a user orders a product, user will receive one email with product data and admin will receive one mail with product data. The email was in HTML designed format. But the problem is, some email servers are sending mails to users and admins properly in html design view. But some email server are sending the email in html coding. I tried and tried by changing Charset values but failed to display the email in design view.

Can anyone plz help me out from it.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: if you have a shopping cart i suppose you got only one email server, why to use more? Oo that said checked correctly the email header?

Comment: What headers are you setting when you send the email? Maybe post the code you're using to generate your email.

Comment: Charset is not the right property to change this. You should use Content-Type. Actually, the best way to do it is to send a multi-part e-mail which contains a plain-text version as the main part and the HTML version as a secundary part.

Comment: @MLeFevre I am using these header                           $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Customer Accounts <info@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're sending mail from php check your Content-Type

```
$header = "From: innova@site.com\r\n";
$header .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . " \r\n";
$header .= "Mime-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/html";
```

Also the server has to define a Mime entry for that type of content with the associated app.
I had a problem with kml files when I moved a web to another server. Links that were previously opened in Google Earth were downloaded im plain text.

A Mime entry in the server solved it.

Comment: The headers seem ok. The charset would only cause undesired character mapping, but would not affect the html rendering. Have checked if there is a relation beteewn the mail server and the mangled contents? do all correct messages come a particular server and viceversa? That would point to a Mime entry problem in the server.